# How to access a Vuex getter from Vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have a `index.js` file which contains my routes and I'm trying to create a `beforeEnter` guard on the admin panel route and only let authenticated admins in. The problem is that when I `console.log(store.getters.isLoggedIn)`, I get this:

```
ƒ isLoggedIn(state) {
    return state.user.token ? true : false
}
```

instead of `true` or `false` and I'm not sure why is this happening. My getter looks like this:

```
getters: {
    isLoggedIn: state => {
        return state.user.token ? true : false
    }
}
```

and my routes are here:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import AdminPanel from '../views/AdminPanel.vue'
import store from "../store/authentication.js";

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: "/admin",
        component: AdminPanel,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            console.log(store.getters.isLoggedIn)
        }
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})

export default router
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import authentication from './authentication'
import cart from './cart'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        authentication,
        cart
    }
})

export default store
```

authentication.js

```
const authentication = {
    state: {
        user: null
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn: state => {
            return state.user.token ? true : false
        }
    }
}

export default authentication
```

Comment: Is `authentication` a module or your main store?

Comment: @Dan It's a module.

Comment: I faced the same problem, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953580/19534949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import the main store instead of importing a Vuex module directly:

```js
import store from "../store/index.js";
```

Your module isn't [namespaced](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing), so now you can access the getter like:

```
store.getters.isLoggedIn
```

If it was namespaced, then you would need to use namespaced module syntax like this:

```js
store.getters['authentication/isLoggedIn']
```

In this syntax, the first half of the string is the module name, then a slash, then the getter name.

When you don't namespace, you run the risk of multiple modules using getters of the same name and it's not clear which module the getter is coming from.

Comment: how would you do if it was namespaced? ie `const { getUser } = useNamespacedGetters<RootGetters>('auth', ['getUser']);`